# Proof verification: show that $\left(\frac{n!e^n}{n^{n+1/2}}\right)_n$ is strictly decreasing

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

Show that the sequence $\left(\frac{n!e^n}{n^{n+1/2}}\right)_n$ is strictly decreasing for any $n \ge 1$.

My work: it is
$$a_{n+1}=\frac{(n+1)!e^{n+1}}{(n+1)^{n+1+1/2}}=\frac{(n+1)n!e^n e}{(n+1)^{n+1/2}(n+1)}$$
$$=\frac{n!e^ne}{n^{n+1/2}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1/2}}=a_n\cdot\frac{e}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}}$$

Since I know that $2<\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n<3$, it follows that $\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}<1/2$; for any $n \ge 1$, $n+1\ge 2$ and using the fact that the square root is increasing it is $\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}} \ge \sqrt{2}$, so $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}} \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

So $\frac{e}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}} <\frac{e}{2\sqrt{2}}$; an approximation of $\sqrt{2}$ by defect is $1.41$, hence it is $2\sqrt{2}>2.82>e$.

So, it follows that $a_{n+1}<a_n \frac{e}{2\sqrt{2}}<a_n\cdot1<a_n \implies a_{n+1}<a_n$.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: No, it is not. In fact  $\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}} < \sqrt{2}$, for any $n>1$. Moreover $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=1$.